# Set height of all childs to 50% of parent fixed height

Tags: html, css, angularjs, flexbox

I've got a wrapper with some boxes within looped from a list with `ng-repeat`. The wrapper has a fixed height of `300px`. When I loop the list and the `length` is 1, so it has just one box, I add a class to the box with `ng-class`, to fill the whole space of the wrapper. This works fine.

If the list has more than one box, I would like to set the `height` of the boxes to `50%` of the wrapper. In the snipped, there are three boxes, which should have a `height` of `150px` (all of them). So the first two boxes should use the half of the `300px` wrapper with a `height` of `150px` and the third box should also have `150px` `height`, but it's not visible (scrollbar with `overflow: auto;` for more than two boxes). I tried this also with a `ng-class` and set a `height` of `50%` to the box, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.myList1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Box 1"
  }];

  $scope.myList2 = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Box 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Box 2"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "Box 3"
    }
  ];
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.fillBox {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.fillHalfBox {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box" ng-repeat="box in myList1" ng-class="{fillBox: myList1.length == 1}">
      {{box.name}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box" ng-repeat="box in myList2" ng-class="{fillHalfBox: myList2.length > 1}">
      {{box.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want this output?   https://i.stack.imgur.com/V97y9.png

Comment: Actually your code seems to work if you fix the typo as stated by PTA below

Comment: @SahilDhir The boxes should be displayed with flex-direction column, so among themselves not in a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this.

```
{fillHalfBox: myList1.length > 1} -> {fillHalfBox: myList2.length > 1}
```

Comment: Can't see why this was downvoted as it seems to fix the issue

Answer (score -3):

Your ng-class expression is not evaluating correctly. Try checking the expression, please. Or you can try other ways of adding the classes conditionally. Read Here,https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass